# How do I keep a prompt running in background?

Tags: shell, background-process, job-control

I am developing a web application in Phoenix and I also just started discovering Unix process management.

I put my app in background, like this:

```
vagrant@dev:/srv/my_app$ iex -S mix phoenix.server &
[1] 8726
```

Then I'd like to `cd` to another directory and do some other work in the main prompt. However, as soon as I do that, the background process stops.

```
vagrant@dev:/srv/my_app$ cd ..

[1]+  Stopped                 iex -S mix phoenix.server  (wd: /srv/my_app)
```

I noticed this happens only in this particular case, because it's a prompt. It doesn't happen with other non-interactive processes (I'm free to change directory and all of that).

I tried the same with `irb`, another prompt, and I get exactly the same behavior.

Why is this happening, and is there any workaround for having a prompt in the background and change directory without it being stopped?

Comment: If you type `jobs -l` at the shell prompt, it will show the reason for the job being stopped. Is it stopped on tty input, or tty output?

Comment: It says it's stopped on tty output -- what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell didn't stop, the progress you sent to the background did (the `iex` process). If you hit "Enter" you'll get a shell prompt back.

Comment: Actually what I want is the `iex` job to not stop, not the original shell prompt. The thing is, the `iex` process is both a *job* and a *prompt*. What I'm trying to achieve is to have the `iex` *job* running in background, but the `iex` *prompt* stopped (so that I can continue using the main shell prompt). Hope that makes sense.
Anyway I realise this is kind of weird, so from now on I'll just run `mix phoenix.server` in the background, which doesn't spawn another prompt.